# SQL Query to show all rows and remove multiple rows on filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following rows:

```
 ID             fk_id       type    comment user    ticket
-----------------------------------------------------------
000000658       135         notes   afdads  abas1   0000000000
000000658       999999      admin           NULL    0000000000
000000659       136         notes   afadsf  admin   0000000001
000000659       999999      admin           NULL    0000000001
000000660       999999      admin           NULL    0000000000
000000661       999999      admin           NULL    0000000006
```

I want to return the row where ID is 000000658 only single result where user is not null, but the same result should also return ID = 000000659 who's user is null as shown below:

```
 ID             fk_id       type    comment user    ticket
-----------------------------------------------------------
000000658       135         notes   fdads   abas1   0000000000
000000659       999999      admin           NULL    0000000001
000000660       999999      admin           NULL    0000000000
000000661       999999      admin           NULL    0000000006
```

My case is to show all complaints on dashboard and show users their own comment.

MY Case is :I have two tables complaint and complaint_detail and I have to show All complaints whever login to my page but show only comments to user that he enters on his ticket no. for this I make a view where my query is :select * from (

```
SELECT 
            COMPLAINT.COMP_TICKET_NUM,
            999999 COMPLAINT_DETAIL_ID ,
            'admin' FLAG,--TO be discuss
            ' ' NOTES,
            null LOGIN_USER,
            CURRENT_STATE, CURRENT_ACTOR,CALCULATED_ACTOR,CURRENT_ORG_UNIT--,
            --TEMP_FLAG
FROM         dbo.COMPLAINT 
left outer join COMPLAINT_DETAIL on COMPLAINT_DETAIL.COMP_TICKET_NUM = COMPLAINT.COMP_TICKET_NUM 
--where COMPLAINT_DETAIL.LOGIN_USER   in ('admin')
union
SELECT 
            COMPLAINT.COMP_TICKET_NUM,
            COMPLAINT_DETAIL.COMPLAINT_DETAIL_ID,
            isnull(COMPLAINT_DETAIL.FLAG,'admin') FLAG,--TO be discuss
            COMPLAINT_DETAIL.NOTES,
            COMPLAINT_DETAIL.LOGIN_USER,

        CURRENT_STATE, CURRENT_ACTOR,CALCULATED_ACTOR,CURRENT_ORG_UNIT--,
            --TEMP_FLAG
FROM         dbo.COMPLAINT 

inner join  COMPLAINT_DETAIL 
on COMPLAINT_DETAIL.COMP_TICKET_NUM =COMPLAINT.COMP_TICKET_NUM
```

Comment: why u want null or one user and not null for other any reason?

Comment: What did you try ? It sounds as simple WHERE (condition1 and condition2)

Comment: Do your use cases have something to do with the "type" field at all? I.e. are you interested in `notes` in some cases, and `admin` in others?

Comment: Are you using this from front end ?

Comment: Yes I am using front end.

Comment: MY Case is :I have two tables complaint and complaint_detail

Comment: @NaushadQamar explain you real scenario because it hard to understand what and how u need those  rows?

Comment: I have updated my question . my scenerio is to show all complaints to all users but display only comments specific to user. to achive this i made detail table where i save comments .

Comment: @NaushadQamar only user and admin can comment on the ticket no one else right?

Comment: no every one can write comment actually comment is user specific and is like for reminder to user.

Comment: @NaushadQamar than how we know it is commented by own user or other user i mean is user is uniques field if ...

Comment: I have front end page where i am getting user from session.

Comment: How may users can you have ?

Answer (score 1):

DISTINCT will give you the ids.
Here is an idea you may try:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(ID), othercolumns
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT(ID), othercolumns
        FROM TABLE_NAME
        WHERE user IS NOT NULL -- All distinct ids where user not null
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT(ID), othercolumns
        FROM TABLE_NAME
        WHERE user IS NULL -- All distinct ids where user IS null
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE1 
WHERE  ( ID = '000000658' 
         AND USER IS NOT NULL ) 
        OR ( ID = '000000659' 
             AND USER IS NULL )
```

But I have a feeling you want something more complicated.
Just let me know what else you want and I'll add it on :-)

**Edit**
After some clarifications, here is a better solution:

```
DECLARE @curr_user VARCHAR(20) = '000000658' 

SELECT ID, 
       FK_ID, 
       TYPE, 
       CASE 
         WHEN @curr_user = USER THEN COMMENT 
         ELSE '' 
       END comment, 
       USER, 
       TICKET 
FROM   TABLE1
```

As requested, the current user (who's ID is passed in a parameter) can see all the complaints but can only see his own comment.
If you need any more details added to this, just let me know.

Comment: it will give only two rows with two ids that u specifiend in you where clause

Comment: I'm aware of that, but that's what was specified in the question: where ID is 000000658 only single result where user is not null, but the same result should also return ID = 000000659 who's user is null.

Comment: As I wrote, it seems there should be something more to this question but I can't just guess what was supposed to be written.

Comment: but expected ouput contaisn four row you can see above...i m not the down voter

Comment: But how do I know what the requested logic is for the output? I don't believe in guessing logic, there's just too high a chance of getting it wrong.

Comment: i think you shouldnt answer if u are not clear of logic your answer should match expedted output....

Comment: I have updated my question  I want all rows but filter on user based the only comment column

Comment: @NaushadQamar, I really want to help you but I find it difficult to understand what the logic you're requesting is.

Comment: Ok here is my scenerio : I have two tables Complaint and complaint_detail.I want to show all complaints to all users but the comment feild should be specific to user. right now i am showing all complaints by select c.*, ' 'comment, LOGIN_USER, from complaint union select c.*, COMPLAINT_DETAIL.comment,
   COMPLAINT_DETAIL.LOGIN_USER from complaint inner join  COMPLAINT_DETAIL 
on COMPLAINT_DETAIL.COMP_TICKET_NUM =COMPLAINT.COMP_TICKET_NUM

Comment: Let see if I understand correctly: You want to show a list of all complaints but limit the visibility of the comment field so that only the user himself can see it. Is this correct?

Comment: How do you know who the current user is? Is there a parameter with this value?

Comment: yes you understand correctly . yes I have parameter of user getting it from session .and I am using hibernate to filter.

Answer (score 0):

U can try it

```
Select * From TableName Where User='abas1' or User is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think What you need is roqw level access, this can be achived as below.
IF you are using it from front end, then you must be asking a user to log in. What i am saying is you have user name.
Then thing is you need to Identify which record will be accessed from a perticular user.
You can include two columns. Defining rights of that user on perticular row and rights of other users.
All those records where user is not the current user and comment is null are available for every one. AND Where comment is not null its available for that user only.

This required more complex work, I am trying to give you an idea. please update me if more details required.

Regards

Ashutosh Arya